enrich Kinesis Data Firehose data
I am looking to enrich Firehose data - add metadata such as timestamps, geo etc. and persist the enriched data into s3.
There are multiple ways I can get it done in the Kinesis Stream, but the Fireshose seem to be lacking direct integrations with lambda to get it done. All the documentation lacks clarity on the best way forward and end up leading to streams. This is an example that starts under Firehose and takes you to Streams.
How should I handle this use case. I can pick up the data once it lands into s3, but I am wondering if there is any simpler pattern to accomplish this.
Please advice.

What makes you think that Firehose can't do that? The docs that you link are specifically about this use case.
